# How to use `flex display` to separate two buttons.

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I want to use `flex display` to separate two buttons.

Now, I am using the `react`.

```
  const style = {
      textAreaStyle: {
        width:'700'
      },
      buttonFatherStyle:{
        display:'flex',
        display:"-webkit-flex",
        flexWrap:  'wrap',
        justifyContent:'around',
        backgroundColor:'red',
      }
    }
```

my `jsx`:

```
          <div style={style.buttonFatherStyle}>
            <FlatButton  style={{backgroundColor:'blue'}} type="submit" disabled={pristine || submitting}> submit </FlatButton>
            <FlatButton  style={{backgroundColor:'green'}} type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}> Clear
            </FlatButton>
          </div>
```

My code does not work.

Comment: Do you try `justifyContent: 'space-between'` ?

Comment: You can read all informations about flex Layout here : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html and you can use too 'margin' propriety (e.g: marginLeft: 20, marginRight: 20) it could work too

Comment: `justifyContent: 'space-between'` or `space-around` ,either is OK.

Comment: Ok cool can you mark my answer as validate ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the documentation :

```
facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html
```

You should try :

```
justifyContent: 'space-between'
```

You can play with marginRight and marginLeft too.
Hope that help

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

```
flatbutton {
    flex-basis: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}
```